# cadastro parcelas php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia, estou fazendo um sistema de promissorias e gostaria de saber como fazer para cadastrar as parcelas no bd com as informações. queria inserir as informações da seguinte maneira

no formulario de cadastro quando eu colocar o valor R$ 300,00 e colocar em 3 parcelas ele inserir na tabela MOVIMENTO e na tabela PARCELAS, ja com as parcelas no valor correto e a quantidade de insert necessario para a quantidade de parcela solicita que como no exemplo sera 3 insert de 100,00

segue estrutura do meu BD

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cad_movimento (
  id_movimento int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_tipomovimento int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_cliente int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  data_movimento int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  descricao_movimento longtext,
  valor_movimento float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_movimento)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cad_parcelas (
  id_parcela int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  id_movimento int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  id_cliente int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  data_movimento int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  vencimento_movimento int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  pagamento_movimento int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  valor_movimento float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_movimento)
);
```

Nao faço a minima ideia de como começar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra fazer essa implementação é relativamente simples, mas tem algo que precisa ser levado em consideração, que é quando a soma das parcelas não resulta no total como no caso de um valor como R$100,00 em 3 parcelas de R$ 33,33. Elaborei o código simulando essa situação. Obs.: O código foi comentado explicando cada passo.

#### Código

```
<?php

// ID do cliente
$idCliente = 1;

// Função round arredonda para duas casas decimais
$valor = round(100, 2);  // R$ 100,00

// Número de parcelas
$parcelas = 3;

// A compra tem entrada?
$entrada = false;


// Insira a movimentação no banco
$sql  = "INSERT INTO cad_movimento (
            id_tipomovimento,
            id_cliente,
            data_movimento,
            descricao_movimento,
            valor_movimento
         ) VALUES (
            1,
            '{$idCliente}',
            NOW(),
            'Moinho de Vento (windmill)',
            '{$valor}'
         )";

   //$con->query($sql);
   echo $sql;
   echo '<br>'.PHP_EOL;

// Pegue do banco o último ID inserido da movimentação
$idMovimento = 1; 


// Calcula o valor da parcela dividindo o total pelo número de parcelas
$valorParcela = round($valor / $parcelas, 2);

// Se tiver entrada diminui o número de parcelas
$qtd = $entrada ? $parcelas - 1 : $parcelas;


// Faz um loop com a quantidade de parcelas
for ($i=($entrada ? 0 : 1); $i <= $qtd; $i++) { 

   // Se for última parcela e a soma das parcelas for diferente do valor da compra
   // ex: 100 / 3 == 33.33 logo 3 * 33.33 == 99.99
   // Então acrescenta a diferença na parcela, assim última parcela será 33.34
   if ($qtd == $i && round($valorParcela * $parcelas, 2) != $valor){ 
      $valorParcela += $valor - ($valorParcela * $parcelas);
   }

   // Caso a variavel $entrada seja true
   // o valor $i na primeira parcela será 0
   // então 30 * 0 == 0
   // será adicionado 0 dias a data, ou seja, a primeira parcela
   // será a data atual
   $dias = 30 * $i;

   // Hoje mais X dias
   // Parcela 1: 30 dias
   // Parcela 2: 60 dias
   // Parcela 3: 90 dias...
   $data = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+{$dias} days"));

   $sql  = "INSERT INTO cad_parcelas (
               id_movimento,
               id_cliente,
               data_movimento,
               vencimento_movimento,
               pagamento_movimento,
               valor_movimento
            ) VALUES (
               '{$idMovimento}',
               '{$idCliente}',
               NOW(),
               '{$data}',
               NULL,
               '$valorParcela'
            )";

   //$con->query($sql);
   echo $sql;

   echo '<br><br>'.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Resultado:

```
INSERT INTO cad_movimento (
   id_tipomovimento,
   id_cliente,
   data_movimento,
   descricao_movimento,
   valor_movimento
) VALUES (
   1,
   '1',
   NOW(),
   'Moinho de Vento (windmill)',
   '100'
)

INSERT INTO cad_parcelas (
   id_movimento,
   id_cliente,
   data_movimento,
   vencimento_movimento,
   pagamento_movimento,
   valor_movimento
) VALUES (
   '1',
   '1',
   NOW(),
   '2015-10-02',
   NULL,
   '33.33'
)

INSERT INTO cad_parcelas (
   id_movimento,
   id_cliente,
   data_movimento,
   vencimento_movimento,
   pagamento_movimento,
   valor_movimento
) VALUES (
   '1',
   '1',
   NOW(),
   '2015-11-01',
   NULL,
   '33.33'
)
INSERT INTO cad_parcelas (
   id_movimento,
   id_cliente,
   data_movimento,
   vencimento_movimento,
   pagamento_movimento,
   valor_movimento
) VALUES (
   '1',
   '1',
   NOW(),
   '2015-12-01',
   NULL,
   '33.34'
)
```

Comment: no seu codigo quando jogo pra salvar no bd ele nao salva as datas como exibe no echo e sim a data atual

Comment: Erro meu, meu campo que nao estava como DATE

Comment: boa noite @kaduAmaral como faço para salvar tbm o numero da parcela e tipo a data correta pois aqui como colocamos o dia da compra como 01/01/2015 por exemplo o vencimento da primeira cai no dia 31/01/2015

Comment: @CristianoCardosoSilva pra salvar o número da parcela é só salvar a variável `$i`. Sobre as datas você tem que calcular. Ali eu calculei 30 dias, mas você também pode [calcular o mês](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875076/adding-three-months-to-a-date-in-php), assim a data cai sempre no mesmo dia do próximo mês.

Answer (score 0):

```
$qtdParc = 3;
$varlorTotal = 300;
$calculoParc = ($valorTotal/$qtdParc);
$data = explode('/','20/11/2015');

for($i=1; $i<=$qtdParc; $i++){
    $retorno = mktime(0, 0, 0, $data[0], $data[1]+$i, $data[2]);
    $dataParc = date('d/m/Y',$retorno).'<br>';
    $sqlInsere = "INSERT INTO tabela (valor, valor_total, parcela, data) VALUES ('$calculoParc', '$valorTotal', '$i', '$dataParc')";
}
```

Comment: e para calcular as datas?

Comment: tipo o vencimento das parcelas a cada 30 dias apos o cadastro

Comment: Ai você monta uma formula básica de calculo de data de parcelas.. Vou montar e coloco pra você

Comment: OK estarei no agurado

Comment: Já alterei a resposta.

Comment: a sua resposta nao consegui salvar no bd, fiz um echo com o sql copiei e apliquei no bd e salvou mais nao nao pegou o valor das prestações

Comment: Tem que customizar, mas ok! Se precisar chame